# Getting maximum height, the user travelled within webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS. I need to take the maximum  height, the user has reached in the webpage.

So, first, I got the maximum height of the webpage.

Second, I passed the scroll events to calculate the scroll from the user. The maximum bottom he goes, I will store the largest scroll value he got, in a variable. Somehow I managed to make it up. But the scroll doesn't help me a lot. I don't know how the get the maximum height, the user has gone.

Help me with some solutions.

Here's the code, I tried:

```js
console.log("Page height:", document.body.scrollHeight);
window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log(
    'top: ' + (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) + ' ' +
    'left: ' + (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
  );
}
```

```html
<html>
  <h1>Check Scrollbar Event</h1>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NjkjzJSx/sample-Img.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:1128px;height:1128px;">
  <p>End of Image</p>
  <p>Second Image!!! </p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/hPMYZVMd/blue-Image.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:1128px;height:1128px;">
  <p>End of Image</p>
  <p>Third Image!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W1HHTjBp/book.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:1128px;height:1128px;">
  <p>End of Image</p>
  <p>Fourth Image!</p>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/C5g2XNWj/inscreen.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:1128px;height:1128px;">
  <p>End of Image</p>

</html>
```

Comment: What you mean `But the scroll doesn't help me a lot`? Just don't forget to save that `max` to some variable for later use

Comment: @Justinas, it showing wrong value. maximum height is 4880. But on end of the page scroll, it shows 4287. on window resizing also, the scroll value gets higher than maximum height. how to solve it. or is there any other way to get the height the user has reached?

Comment: You mark only scroll height to top of window (when not scrolled you will get 0 instead of window height). So you need to add window height to that offset to get bottom of window. Basically all XY-location tools gives you top-left corner location

Comment: Thanks....can u show me in code....